# npm twitter API not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, npm

Trying to perform a basic stream using an example. I have the code:

```
var twit = require('twitter');
var twitter = new twit({
    consumer_key:         '[KEY]', 
    consumer_secret:      '[SECRET]',
    access_token:         '[TOKEN]',
    access_token_secret:  '[TOKEN-SECRET]'
});

twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {track: 'food'}, function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
   console.log(tweet.text);
  });

  stream.on('error', function(error) {
    throw error;
  });
});
```

Doent responds with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that in official document the key name should be:

```
var client = new Twitter({
   consumer_key: '',
   consumer_secret: '',
   access_token_key: '', // instead of: access_token:
   access_token_secret: ''
});
```